# Developing a web page which invokes web services through CXF

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, cxf

I have already generated the files using wsdl2Java and created the proxy client in JAVA.I am using Apache CXF framework and using Maven as Build Management tool.  I can run the JAVA application and consume the service using JAVA. There is no problem with JAVA implementation.

The need is I need to invoke and request the same web service from PHP or JSP file and display the result in PHP or JSP file. I would like to use the present JAVA code. I don't know how to invoke the JAVA code from PHP or JSP page.

Please help me with the solutions.

Comment: F-f-f. You need to choose: either you go PHP or JSP :) Do you need to call Web Service from PHP using the Java client you've wrote? When you need to know how how to [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) you Java program, which parameters to pass in and how to parse results. Alternatively you can use [`SoapClient`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2599374/267197) class. For JSP it is easier: you just need to import your client code and use it. Do you have a good command on JSP?

Comment: This is a very misleading comment, in many regards.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.I have decided, I will choose JSP . I have basic knowledge of JSP . I have all Java class file ready. I only need now is the communication between JSP and JAVA. how can we achieve that?

Comment: Is the inclusion of following code in JSP is good approach .  <jsp:useBean id="currencyConverter" scope="session" class="net.webservicex.CurrencyConvertor" /> Help me @Perception

Answer (score 0):

You have created a web service, so your design should be centered around that. For Java programs (including JSP's) you can use the generated client classes to access the web service. For PHP I would recommend using one of the many SOAP client libraries to process and consume your WSDL. You might want to take a look at [wsdl2php](http://www.urdalen.no/wsdl2php/), [NuSoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/), or [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.I have decided, I will choose JSP . I have basic knowledge of JSP . I have all Java class file ready. I only need now is the communication between JSP and JAVA. how can we achieve that?